# Direct link to comments that are being loaded asynchronously?

Tags: python, jquery, xmlhttprequest, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I am playing around with change.org and trying to download a couple of comments on a petition. For this, I would like to know where the comments are being pulled from when the user clicks on "load more reasons"  For an example, look here:

http://www.change.org/petitions/tell-usda-to-stop-using-pink-slime-in-school-food

Looking at the XHR requests in Chrome, I see requests being sent to http://www.change.org/petitions/tell-usda-to-stop-using-pink-slime-in-school-food/opinions?page=2&role=comments   Of course, the page number varies with the number of times comments are being loaded.

However, this link leads to a blank page when I try it in a browser. Is this because of some missing data in the url or is this a result of some authentication step within the javascript that makes the request in the first place?

Any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks to the first response, I see that the data is being received when I use the console.  How do I receive the same data when making the request from a python script. Do I *have* to mimic the browser or is there a way to just use urllib?

Answer (score 1):

They must be validating the source of the request. If you go to the site open the console and run this:

```
$.get('http://www.change.org/petitions/tell-usda-to-stop-using-pink-slime-in-school-food/opinions?page=2&role=comments',{},function(data){console.log(data);});
```

You will see the data come back

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I do see the data in the console when I run this. Now is there a way to receive the data without having to go through the website. That is, what can I do to fetch the data from this url using a python script.